# When creating a table getting an error "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a table using this statements in SQL but it says missing right parenthesis.

Here is the statement

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( 
        Job_ID Int (20) Job_Title Varchar (255), 
        Min_Salary Decimal (25), 
        Max_Salary Decimal (25), 
);
```

Comment: Try to remove the last coma in your parenthesis

Comment: Loving the variety of the answers :P

Comment: one comma -> six answers, real problem -> no answers :D

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( 
      Job_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Job_Title VARCHAR(255)
    , Min_Salary DECIMAL(25)
    , Max_Salary DECIMAL(25)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> change int(20) to just int
>   set comma  : `Job_ID Int , Job_Title Varchar (255)`

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( 
        Job_ID Int,
        Job_Title Varchar (255), 
        Min_Salary Decimal (25), 
        Max_Salary Decimal (25)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra unnecessary comma at the last column, **remove it**. Also you missed a comma after the `Job_ID` definition. And an `INT` does not have size so change `int(20)` to just `int`

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( 
        Job_ID Int, --missed this one
        Job_Title Varchar (255), 
        Min_Salary Decimal (25), 
        Max_Salary Decimal (25), 
);
                               | here, this one is unnecessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add a coma betwin Job_ID Int (20) and Job_Title Varchar (255)

Answer (score 0):

This statement must be better:

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( 
    Job_ID Int (20),
    Job_Title Varchar (255), 
    Min_Salary Decimal (25), 
    Max_Salary Decimal (25) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes programming errors can be a bit funny. They're about as clueless as we are sometimes :p

You're missing a comma at the start, and you have one extra comma on the end.

```
CREATE TABLE Bk_Jobs ( Job_ID Int (20), 
          Job_Title Varchar (255), 
          Min_Salary Decimal (25), 
          Max_Salary Decimal (25) 
);
```